# PHP need fputcsv to print NULL instead of an empty cell

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fputcsv

I am using fputcsv to create a csv file from a mysql table, everything works fine except if there's an empty column or NULL in the database table, as then the output csv cell is empty, rather than printing NULL.

Is this normal behaviour?

Heres the script im using

```
        private function me_calendar_report() {

        ini_set("memory_limit","256M");

        $calendar = array();

        $this->load->model('me_reports_model');

        $calendar = $this->me_reports_model->get_all_resource_calendar();

        $headers = array(
            array('id', 'Resource ID', 'Job ID', 'From date', 'To date', 'Colour', 'Resource Type', 'Is provisional', 'Fixed price'
            ));

        $calendar_data = array();

        foreach($calendar as $i) {
            $calendar_data[] = array(
                $i->id,
                $i->resource_id,
                $i->job_id,
                $i->from_date,
                $i->to_date,
                $i->colour,
                $i->resource_type,
                $i->is_provisional,
                $i->fixed_price
            );
        }

        $csv = array_merge($headers, $calendar_data);

        $fp = fopen('report_repository/resource_calendar-' . date('d-m-Y') . '.csv', 'w');

        foreach ($csv as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }

        fclose($fp);
        return 'report_repository/resource_calendar-' . date('d-m-Y') . '.csv';

    }
```

Comment: _“Is this normal behaviour?”_ – I’d think so, since `echo NULL;` also just yields an empty output. But you could easily solve this by replacing `NULL` values with the _string_ value `'NULL'` while populating the array in the loop.

Comment: You can either change your sql query, which I assume is in `get_all_resource_calendar()`, to change `NULL` to `NULL` values, ie. `SELECT CASE WHEN \`colour\` IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE \`colour\` END as \`colour\` OR in your `foreach($calendar as $i)` loop -> `$i->colour = (trim($i->colour)=='') ? 'NULL':$i->colour;`

Comment: This worked for me $i->colour = (trim($i->colour)=='') ? 'NULL':$i->colour;

Comment: It would be great if fputcsv resulted in null values showing up as a blank like `"value1",,"value3"` and empty strings showed up like `"value1","","value3"` but I'm probably missing something. To work around nulls I am using JSON format instead of CSV for export/import.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The CSV has no way to display null values, NULL would actually be the string "NULL".

You can pre-process before writing if that's what you want:

```
foreach ($calendar_data as $key => $value) {
  if ($value === null) {
    $calendar_data[$key] = "NULL";
  }
}
```

Note that you are essentially creating your own specialized CSV format, which you should keep in mind if anyone else needs to use it. Similarly, when loading it, you would also pre-process the line after retrieving it with fgetcsv:

```
foreach ($calendar_data as $key => $value) {
  if ($value === "NULL") {
    $calendar_data[$key] = null;
  }
}
```

There will still be ambiguity though, you have just moved it from the empty string vs null to the string "NULL" vs null. If that's a problem you could use YAML, JSON or an SQL dump instead.

Answer (score 1):

In modern versions of PHP, `null` value is rendered as an empty string in csv.
See this code:

```
<?php    
$filePointer = \fopen('php://memory', 'wb');
$row= ['ciao', 'bo;no', null, '', 12];
\fputcsv($filePointer, $row, ';');
\rewind($filePointer);
$a = \stream_get_contents($filePointer);
\fclose($filePointer);
echo $a;
```

see also https://3v4l.org/BoeJF